# JavaScript and JQuery with Telerik help needed

Tags: javascript, jquery

Dev Gurus:  Need some help.  I have a external .js file that has the following function:

```
function bindDates(effDate, endDate, attrType) {
    //Declare variables to be used in the JavaScript Function
    var effDateID = effDate.get_id();
    var endDateID = endDate.get_id();
    var tmp = attrType;

    //RBD THIS IS KEY TO THE DATEPICKER BOXES>>>>>>>> THIS IS THE KEY -------------      TRY TO BREAK UP>>>>>>>>>
    //$(effDate.get_element()).on('validDateEntered', { effID: effDateID, endID: endDateID, type: tmp }, function (evt) {
    //    setEffectiveDates($find(evt.data.effID), $find(evt.data.endID), evt.data.type);
    //});

    $(effDate.get_element()).on('validDateEntered', { effID: effDateID, endID: endDateID, type: tmp }, function (evt) {
        setEffectiveDates($find(evt.data.effID), $find(evt.data.endID), evt.data.type);
    });

    effDate.add_dateSelected(function (sender, args) {
        validateDatesRange(effDate, endDate);
    });

    effDate.get_dateInput().add_blur(function (sender, args) {
        validateDatesRange(effDate, endDate);
    });

    //$(endDate.get_element()).on('validDateEntered', { effID: effDateID, endID: endDateID, type: tmp }, function (evt) {
    //    setEffectiveDates($find(evt.data.effID), $find(evt.data.endID), evt.data.type);
    //});

    endDate.add_dateSelected(function (sender, args) {
        validateDatesRange(effDate, endDate);
    });

    endDate.get_dateInput().add_blur(function (sender, args) {
        validateDatesRange(effDate, endDate);
    });
}
```

Need help on understanding the following

```
$(effDate.get_element()).on('validDateEntered', { effID: effDateID, endID: endDateID, type: tmp }, function (evt) {
    setEffectiveDates($find(evt.data.effID), $find(evt.data.endID), evt.data.type);
});
```

I am not sure what the 'validDateEntered' means.   this is code I am working on from a past developer.    What seems to be happening is that the date will get set if it is valid, but I need it to set NO MATTER WHAT.

Add later:

```
 function validateDatesRange(effDateCtrl, endDateCtrl) {
    var result = true,
        effDate = effDateCtrl.get_selectedDate(),
        endDate = endDateCtrl.get_selectedDate(),
        cell = $(effDateCtrl.get_element()).parents('td').first();

    if (effDate && endDate) {
        if (effDate > endDate) {
            var div = "<div class='errorMessage' style='display:none;'>Effective date must be less than end date.</div>";
            $(div).prependTo(cell).fadeIn();
            result = false;
        }
    }

    if (result) {
        cell.find('div.errorMessage').fadeOut(200, null, function () { $(this).remove(); });
        $(effDateCtrl.get_element()).trigger('validDateEntered');
    }
    return result;
}
```

When the page loads it will populate multiple grids.   The grids have an edit button.   When you click the edit button a panel displays and shows the effDate and endDate controls.

The effDate populates when you click the edit button once, but the endDate does not.   If you click the edit button again the endDate control will populate.   I need them populated on the same click.   I feel dumb because I cannot trap the issue.  I wish I could trap the edit event, but do not even see it in the grid.   Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Reading the following, but still do not get it... http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handlereventObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'validDateEntered' is a custom event. You should search the code for `.trigger('validDateEntered');`, since that will be the source of the event. That will give you a clue how to trigger an event even if the data isn't valid.

There is some discussion of custom events here: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

**UPDATED after OP edits**:

So it looks like `bindDates` says that whenever a date is selected or the date selector is blurred, call `validateDatesRange`. If the dates are valid, `validateDatesRange` triggers a 'validDateEntered' custom event and returns true. If they aren't, it returns false without triggering an event. When `validateDatesRange` is triggered, the effDate sets the effective dates.

The easiest way to set the effective dates regardless if they are valid (and probably safest way, considering that you don't understand the app yet) is to replace `validateDatesRange()` with

```
function validateDatesRange(effDateCtrl, endDateCtrl) {
    $(effDateCtrl.get_element()).trigger('validDateEntered');    
}
```

Comment: There is another function ----

Comment: function validateDatesRange(effDateCtrl, endDateCtrl) {
        var result = true,
            effDate = effDateCtrl.get_selectedDate(),
            endDate = endDateCtrl.get_selectedDate(),
            cell = $(effDateCtrl.get_element()).parents('td').first();

Comment: cfs, thanks for the help, however the issue is not the effDateCtrl it is the endDateCtrl.   It does not seem to get wired up to the value.  I see the JSON values in the pass back using Fiddler.  Any other help would be great.

Comment: I am looking at the code and see --- $(effDateCtrl.get_element()).trigger('validDateEntered');   What is 'validDateEntered'????  I understand 'click' or other events, but what the heck is validDateEntered???

Comment: @Moojjoo See my answer above for explanations of what 'validDateEntered' is. You will need to read the jQuery docs I linked to, they will help explain what custom events are.

Comment: The only line is the following: if (result) {
            cell.find('div.errorMessage').fadeOut(200, null, function () { $(this).remove(); });    <----  Could this be the problem because the endDateCtrl does not have this trigger.  Please see above I am going to explain the lifecycle to this issue. 
            $(effDateCtrl.get_element()).trigger('validDateEntered');            
        }
        return result;

Comment: @Moojjoo I'm not sure what issue you're having with the above line. If you are seeing errors in the code, I suggest posting a new question including what error messages your seeing and what you've tried to resolve it. 

The original question you posted asked to clarify what the code was doing, which I feel like I have answered. If you agree, it's polite at StackOverflow to accept an answer. Good luck!